# Writing 'reactive' WebFlux controller

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm trying to convert WebMVC controller to WebFlux controller returning `Mono<Resource>`.

The old `WebMVC` controller looks like below.

```java
@GetMapping("/resources/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getCustomer(@RequestParam String id) {
    if(id.length != 10) {
        // set ResponseEntity status 400 and then return it
    }

    val resource = resourceService.getResourceById(id);    
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(resource);
}
```

How can I have `if` block more compatible with the `Reactive Programming`?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried if ... else ... like @nipuna-saranga's answer below, but couldn't make sure if this kine of code is correct or not in terms of reactive programming.

Comment: he has provided a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Functional endpoints you could do something like that.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getCustomer(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

  if (serverRequest.pathVariable("id").length() != 10) {

    return ServerResponse
        .status(400)
        .build();

  } else {

    return ServerResponse
        .ok()
        .body(
            resourceService.getResourceById(serverRequest.pathVariable("id")),
            Resource.class
        );

  }

}
```

Above mentioned is more readable for me. But you could start with `Mono.just(serverRequest.pathVariable("id"))`, if you really want to maintain stream even within methods, as below.

```
return Mono.just(serverRequest.pathVariable("id"))
  .filter(id -> id.length() == 10)
  .flatMap(resourceService::getResourceById)
  .flatMap(resource -> ServerResponse
      .ok()
      .body(
          resourceService.getResourceById(serverRequest.pathVariable("id")),
          Resource.class
      )
  )
  .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.status(400).build());
```

Similarly if you are using annotated controllers, something like below seems more readable (for me :)).

```
@GetMapping(path = "/resources/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Mono<Resource>> getCustomer(@PathVariable String id) {

  if (id.length() != 10) {

    return ResponseEntity
            .status(400)
            .build();

  } else {

    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .body(resourceService
            .getResourceById(id));

  }

}
```

Official documentation is a good enough reference:
Two relevant sections in documentation

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-controller
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn

Comment: I don't think ResponseEntity<Mono<Resource>> is reactive. While Mono<ResponseEntity<Resource>> is reactive

Comment: @PatPatPat I was wondering the same for a while, do you have a reference ? I could not find any thing definitive. I have seen both ways in code examples and tutorials. I saw a github issue closed which was posted by a person similar to your name, was that you? But that also give no definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

**U need to create the handler,router for webflux functional flow**

```
@Component
```

public class SampleHandlerFunction {

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> flux(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

    return ServerResponse.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(
                    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
                            .log(), Integer.class
            );
}

public Mono<ServerResponse> mono(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

    return ServerResponse.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(
                    Mono.just(1)
                            .log(), Integer.class
            );
}
```

**router**

```
@Configuration
```

public class RouterFunctionConfig {

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(com.Reactive.SpringReactive.handler.SampleHandlerFunction handlerFunction){

    return RouterFunctions
            .route(GET("/functional/flux").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),handlerFunction::flux)
            .andRoute(GET("/functional/mono").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),handlerFunction::mono);

}
```

}