# Using netflix-dgs with WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, netflix-dgs

This might be a dumb questions, with me being a novice getting starting with the whole reactive programming methodology.
Task:
But I'm working on developing a Spring Boot Netflix DGS based GraphQL API
Implementation:
So I am using the standard netflix platform dgs libraries and scalars and all that, and in addition i just added "spring-boot-starter-webflux" dependency.
And then in the DgsQuery method i'm returning Mono instead of just String

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ....
```

in the POM
and

```
@DgsQuery
public Mono<String> sayHello() {
    return Mono.just("Hello, World!");
}
```

Question:
Will that be enough to call the graphql API "reactive"?

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453427/175554) for more details how to write reactive spring controllers.

Yes using Mono or Flux will make the controller reactive. and [looks like](https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/discussions/374#discussioncomment-944525) netflix-dgs supports it already.